# Incorrect string value: '\xCC_a' for column when inserting

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to run a sql query but get the following error:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xCC_a' for column
```

CSV File line that breaks mysql query:

```
Juan Gordon,GarcÃ_a,noman@gmail.com,,,,,,,,,,y,
```

SQL Error:

```
<p>Error Number: 1366</p><p>Incorrect string value: '\xCC_a' for column 'last_name' at row 1</p><p>INSERT INTO `phppos_people` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone_number`, `address_1`, `address_2`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `country`, `comments`) VALUES ('Juan Gordon', 'Garc�_a', 'noman@test.com', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')</p><p>Filename: /Library/WebServer/Documents/phppos/PHP-Point-Of-Sale/models/person.php</p><p>Line Number: 75</p>  </div>
```

last_name is `varchar(255) utf8_unicode_ci`

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

Example CSV code

```
?>


last_name = GarcÌ_a
```

UPDATE: I just learned that when saving the file as a .csv in excel the encoding is: Westren (Mac OS Roman) with CR as line breaks.

I think that file encoding might cause the problem. But I need to support it.

Comment: Are you sure, that php reads the file correctly? Try to print the value, that it reads from csv file into another file. Why print into the file? Cause the console has it's own output encoding. In the file, check what value did it read does it have the correct encoding. I have inserted special characters like ç and é into unicode mysql fields without any problems.

Comment: I put the file file through the above php function and the last_name field is shown above (GarcÌ_a), Is this not valid?

Comment: Looks good. Did you try SQL request before the insert: "SET NAMES utf-8;"?

Comment: I agree with @user4035: you most likely have not correctly set the [connection character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html).  But is there any particular reason you're not using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html)?

Comment: The char set is utf8. I am using codeigniter and you set this up in a config file. I am NOT using LOAD DATA INFILE as this is a user uploaded file.

Comment: See update about file encoding for .csv file

Comment: @ChrisMuench decode the text from Westren encoding to utf-8

Comment: How would to decode it? How can I detect that this is the case?

Comment: @ChrisMuench try this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: @user4035 how would I use this function in a generic way? I don't want  to convert if it won't fail when inserting into database.

Comment: @ChrisMuench In this case you'll have to check, whether special characters exist in the string, and then - use the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only Excel that exports to Mac OS Roman apparently is MS Excel for OSX. Unfortunately I don't have this so I can't check how to export with the correct character set

You now have two choices

**a) Convert the CSV to UTF-8 using [iconv](http://ss64.com/bash/iconv.html) for example**

```
iconv -f MACROMAN -t UTF8 < yourfile.csv > yourfile-utf8.csv
```

**b) Set the connection charset to the character set of the file before you import**

```
SET NAMES macroman;
```

In codeigniter this would look like this

```
$this->db->simple_query('SET NAMES \'macroman\'');
```

After your import is done, don't forget to set it back

```
$this->db->simple_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
```

**Explanation:**

If your connection charset is UTF-8, your database excepts UTF-8 encoded data. If you set the connection charset to `macroman` and the columns you write to are UTF-8, MySQL will automatically convert this for you.

> From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html
>
> SET NAMES 'charset_name' [COLLATE 'collation_name']
>
> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the  server. Thus, SET NAMES 'cp1251' tells the server, “future incoming messages from this  client are in character set cp1251.” It also specifies the character set that the server  should use for sending results back to the client. (For example, it indicates what character set to use for column values if you use a SELECT statement.)

On my freeBSD machine, MySQL has the macroman character set compiled in, I suppose you'll also have this.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLLATIONS WHERE CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'macroman';
+---------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+
| COLLATION_NAME      | CHARACTER_SET_NAME | ID | IS_DEFAULT | IS_COMPILED | SORTLEN |
+---------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+
| macroman_general_ci | macroman           | 39 | Yes        | Yes         |       1 |
| macroman_bin        | macroman           | 53 |            | Yes         |       1 |
+---------------------+--------------------+----+------------+-------------+---------+
```

Also see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Just curiousity: which solution did you choose?